# Update db with hashed pw using the password_hash and password_verify

Tags: php, mysqli

I am just a little confused as to where I can fit it in this file. The file is for pw validation currently but I would like the pw to be hashed using password_hash. That being said I understand how password hashing works and more confused on how to properly implement it into my case. I've found many examples of creating a pw and hashing it but need help pulling pw from db and hashing it and updating the db. After I have that I can just use something along the lines of

if( password_verify($userpassword,hash)){
do something }

Or am I looking at this the wrong way and need to take a different approach. I fairly new to php and it is not my strong suite any help or info would be great.

Comment: Are you saying you have an entire database full of passwords in the raw, and you would like to convert them all to their hashed versions?

Comment: yes that is exactly what im saying I have alot of raw pw and want to hash them and verify the hashed pw then validate pw for login

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What Sammitch posted is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a single, separate script to run *one time* to update all the plaintext passwords to those generated by `password_hash()`.

Something like:

```php
// FOR UPDATE locks the rows
$res = $dbh->query('SELECT id, password FROM users FOR UPDATE;');

$update = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE id = ?;');
foreach($res->fetch_all() as $row) {
  // https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash
  if( password_needs_rehash($row['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT) {
    $hash = password_hash($row['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $update->bind_param('ss', $hash, $row['id']);
    $update->execute();
  }
}
```

Usually you might implement `password_needs_rehash()` into a login workflow to upgrade hashes on-the-fly, but if you have everything in plaintext you don't have to wait for the login to happen, and you absolutely *need* to get those all hashed *ASAP*.